# I wanna implement touch Gestures for a Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, javascriptmvc

I am developing a website for a desktop. Now I want to implement a feature where if the website is opened in a mobile phone or other touch device, I want my program to detect the device and activate the touch functions. How can I do that?

Which framework I have to use? Currently I am using JavaScript (jQuery) in JavaScriptMVC framework.

Suggest to me a library that supports touch functions (like jquery.js). I don't need a plug-in, I want to write my own program.

Comment: sorry, can't help but notice your, ``i Am`` should be ``I am``

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting a question, please take a moment before clicking Post Your Question to read through it and correct the worst of the typos and such. We use proper capitalization and such in writing for a reason: It aids comprehension. You clearly have quite good English skills even if it's not your first language, and know the basic rules ("I" is always capitalized, etc.), I sure you know it's "using" not "suing", etc. It's respectful to the community you're asking help of to take that moment to clean things up. (You can use the "edit" link to do that now, if you like.)

Comment: ^ @LocustHorde - you can edit posts to improve them `:)`

Comment: @halfer, yes, I've tried it before, but I always get `edits should exceed certain characters`` error, and I know this is just two letters (and not sure they even count!)

Comment: @LocustHorde - I agree, it's a silly restriction. In general I've stopped correcting minor errors despite my unreasonable intolerance for them; however at least it gives more time to improve posts that _really_ need editing!

Comment: @LocustHorde Yes i did not observe my spelling mistakes.. surel i'll take care of them

Comment: @halfer  Thanks gentleman for the defense.But its fair they asked for some respect to the community. We loose no penny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Modernizer to detect client cababilities, and modify your functionality accordingly.
http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [atJQuerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) for enabling gesture capabilities. And yes, use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect the client device.